# Cakephp not updating model

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to update a record with the CakePHP framework, but I'm getting an error which tells me I can't update. But I can't find where the error is coming from.

This is the place where the if statement fails in the controller:

**Controller/InvoicesController.php**

```
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        $this->Invoice->id = $id;

        if ($this->Invoice->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invoice updated'), 'flash-success');
        } else {        
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Please try again'), 'flash-error');
            debug($this->validationErrors, true);
            pr($this->request->data);
        }
    }
```

Debug results in this:

```
/app/Controller/InvoicesController.php (line 73)
null
```

And this is the data coming from CakePHP when I try to save:

```
Array
(
    [Invoice] => Array
        (
            [date] => Array
                (
                    [day] => 05
                    [month] => 01
                    [year] => 2015
                )

            [period] => 14
            [notes] => 
        )

)
```

Why can't CakePHP update my record?

Comment: Can you also post your Model and can you print the data that you're trying to save? i.e. show what's $id and $this->Invoice just before doing the save() command

Answer (score 0):

For update, request data must contain id value

example

```
$this->request->data['Invoice']['id'] = $id;
```

or in your edit.ctp  add

```
$this->Form->hidden('id');
```